# What does the number after suggested questions mean?

Tags: discussion

Like

> What’s the point of put some
>   javascript to head and others to end
>   of body? (4)

What does (4) mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the number of answers already supplied to the question.

This way you can see that when you are asking a question, you may be asking a duplicate that already has potential answers for you to look at.